# Why is my BTDF build msi failing to deploy into Biztalk?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-deployment, btdf

I have a dev machine where I do my development for biztalk 2020 using framework 4.8 and BTDF V5.8. When I install my apps using the Visual studio 2019 Biztalk extensions I can install the applications no issues. And the with the following settings in BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets.

```
<Target Name="SetToolsVersionParam">
<CreateProperty Value="/tv:12.0" Condition="'$(MSBuildToolsVersion)' == '12.0'">
<Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="ToolsVersionParam" />
</CreateProperty>
</Target>
```

When I build an msi of the same project and I deploy it to biztalk sever in UAT, I need to update the SetToolsVersionParam to 4.

```
<Target Name="SetToolsVersionParam">
<CreateProperty Value="/tv:4.0" Condition="'$(MSBuildToolsVersion)' == '4.0'">
<Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="ToolsVersionParam" />
</CreateProperty>
</Target>
```

Question why can I not leave my SetToolsVersionParam at 12 for deployment to the UAT server like on my dev machine?

Another Question, as I do both both biztalk and .net6 development on the dev machine, this has not been an issue, however I recently need to install the .net6 runtime on the UAT server for a new service and the fix above for SetToolsVersionParam stopped working.

I cannot get any new msi's to install on the server. I get the following irrespective if the SetToolsVersionParam is 12 or 4. Error MSB4067: The element  beneath element  is unrecognized.

I search all post regarding BTDF, but I have been unable to find a resolution as yet.

Any help will be appreciated.

---

**Update**:
I ran the following PowerShell command between the 2 (Working server and one that is failing) the result is the same.

```
dir HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\


    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions


Name                           Property
----                           --------
2.0                            MSBuildToolsPath : C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\
3.5                            MSBuildToolsPath : C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\
4.0                            FrameworkSDKRoot      : $(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
                                                       SDKs\Windows\v7.0A@InstallationFolder)
                               MSBuildRuntimeVersion : 4.0.30319
                               MSBuildToolsPath      : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
                               MSBuildToolsPath32    : $(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSB
                               uild\ToolsVersions\4.0@MSBuildT
                                                       oolsPath)
                               MSBuildToolsRoot      : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\
                               SDK35ToolsPath        : $(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
                                                       SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\WinSDK-NetFx35Tools-x86@InstallationFolder)
                               SDK40ToolsPath        : $(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
                                                       SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86@InstallationFolder)
```

When installing the MSI I get the following output:

```
GetSoftwarePaths:
  Using .NET Framework Install Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319'.
  Using BizTalk Install Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server\'.
  Using Deployment Framework Install Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\BTS_Nexus for BizTalk 1.0.0\1.0\Deployment\'.
  Using Deployment Framework Tools Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\BTS_Nexus for BizTalk 1.0.0\1.0\Deployment\Framework\De
  ployTools'.
  Using BizTalk ESB Toolkit Install Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk ESB Toolkit\'.
ExportSettings:
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\BTS_Nexus for BizTalk 1.0.0\1.0\Deployment\Framework\DeployTools\EnvironmentSettingsExporter.
  exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\BTS_Nexus for BizTalk 1.0.0\1.0\Deployment\EnvironmentSettings\SettingsFileGenerator.xml
  " "C:\Program Files (x86)\BTS_Nexus for BizTalk 1.0.0\1.0\Deployment\EnvironmentSettings"
  Environment Settings Spreadsheet to XML Exporter 1.7.0
  [https://github.com/tfabraham/EnvironmentSettingsManager]
  Copyright (C) 2007 Thomas F. Abraham.  All Rights Reserved.

  Importing from SettingsFileGenerator.xml...

  Output format is XmlPreprocess (multi-file).

  Exporting to Exported_LocalSettings.xml...
  Exporting to Exported_DevSettings.xml...
  Exporting to Exported_UatSettings.xml...
  Exporting to Exported_ProdSettings.xml...

  Finished.
LaunchServerDeployWizard:
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\BTS_Nexus for BizTalk 1.0.0\1.0\Deployment\Framework\DeployTools\SetEnvUI.exe" /c:InstallWiza
  rd.xml /p:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" /a:"Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.Server
  Execute.targets /t:Deploy /clp:NoSummary /nologo /p:Interactive=True /p:ProjectFile=Deployment.btdfproj "

Build started 30/06/2023 4:16:33 PM.
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 2.0.50727.9031
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.9058]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2005. All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\DeploymentFrameworkForBizTalk\5.0\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets(1801,2): error MSB4067: The element <ItemDefinitionGroup> beneath element <Project> is unrecognized.
Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\BTS_Nexus for BizTalk 1.0.0\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.ServerE
xecute.targets" on node 1 (Deploy target(s)).
Copy:
  Copying file from "..\..\DeployResults\DeployResults.txt" to "..\..\DeployResults\DeployResults_UAT-BIZTALK1_20230630
  _1616.txt".
  copy /y "..\..\DeployResults\DeployResults.txt" "..\..\DeployResults\DeployResults_UAT-BIZTALK1_20230630_1616.txt"
PauseForError:
  *************************************
  ************* FAILED! ***************
  *************************************
  Press a key to continue...
```

When I compare this with the above output with the msi output on the server that worked I see a difference in the GetSoftwarePaths section:

```
Using .NET Framework Install Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727'.
                Using BizTalk Install Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server\'.
                Using Deployment Framework Install Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\BTS_Nexus for BizTalk 1.0.0\1.0\Deployment\'.
                Using Deployment Framework Tools Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\BTS_Nexus for BizTalk 1.0.0\1.0\Deployment\Framework\DeployTools'.
                Using BizTalk ESB Toolkit Install Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk ESB Toolkit\'.
```

This one that working uses

```
Using .NET Framework Install Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
```

and the one that is not working is using

```
Using .NET Framework Install Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319'.
```

Where and how do I change this to use the correct framework?
As this seems to be the issue.

Comment: Some idea's that you might investigate. Remove the toolsVersion attribute completely. It should now use "The Default". Not a big fan of defaults, but this one might be just what works for you. MSI  install issue: Are your 'InstallWizard.xml' 'UninstallWizard.xml' well-formed?

Comment: Hi Marvin, I have an installed the same MSI on another server with no issues. So I don't think it is mal-formed xml. But I try your other suggestion.

Comment: IINM, the MSI only installs the items in the MSI content. It does not use BTDF, it installs the BTDF deployment file, dll's, ,makes directories, etc. Just to be 100% clear, we're talking about running the MSI to install files (and registered the installation in windows). NOT running the MSBuild against the Deployment.btdfproj file?

Comment: Hi Marvin, yes this issue is happening when I deploy the MSI on one server, there is no issues to create the msi or even install the project using Visual studio.

Comment: Given the error,  it IS an MSB(uild) error. The error refers to using invalid elements according to the schema. Given this is happening on one machine, i would cross compare the installed MSBuild versions/path to it, etc. You can also manually run the build with verbose mode on, which might give you more insight.

Comment: Your 'failing' server is running on MSBuild 2.0 (2005). (/p:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe") => MSBuild 2.0. Was expecting 4. 8.3761.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to get my msi installed.
After comparing the Microsoft.Net on both servers I found the an extra folder Primary Interop Assemblies which I renamed the folder.
I also compared the contents of Microsoft.Net and MSBuild folders between the 2 servers.
There was a slight change in file BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets, which from comparing the contents seemed to be more formatting, but I replaced the file with the file from the server that works.

This worked and the msi installed.

Thanks for all the help and support.

Comment: Glad you got it solved!